# In class A, I want to go throught the keySet of a HashMap in class B

Tags: java, methods, hashmap, keyset

I want to go through each key in a keySet of a HashMap from another class. 
Right now this is what I have:

**Admin.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap

public class Admin {
public static HashMap<String, Person> person = new HashMap<String, Person>();

    public static void main (String [] args) {
         for (String key: person.get("James").getHashMap().keySet()) {
         System.out.println(key);
    }

}
```

**Person.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap

public class Person {
public static HashMap<String, Book> book = new HashMap<String, Book>();
private static String title = "";


    public Book (String titleIn) {
         title = titleIn;
    }

    public HashMap getHashMap(){
         return book;
    }


}
```

I think I can't do this beacause I am unable to use HashMap commands on a HashMap that isn't stored in the same class.

Is there another method I could use? Am I calling it wrong from Admin.java?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `getHashMap` method returns a raw `HashMap` in your `Person` class.

Raw maps are not parametrized, so the type for their key is `Object` implicitly.

You need to change it to:

```
public Map<String, Book> getHashMap(){
   return book;
}
```

... in order to be able to reference a key as `String`.

**Edit**

You also need to either change the `book` variable to instance (as opposed to `static`), or make the `getHashMap` method static.

The latter is probably advised against, as it would return the same object for all your `Person` instances.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! I just had to change "Map" to "HashMap", is there any difference between the two, or is Map just a shorter name for HashMap?

Comment: @Jalokoh `Map` is the interface implemented by `HashMap`. Part of the "code to an interface" principle.

Comment: Btw you **should** be able to return `Map<String, Book>` if you import it.

Comment: Ah okay, yeah that would! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Since it is static and public , you are allowed use it from anywhere of your project. Just write

```
Admin.person
```

For ex

```
public class Person {

...
....
        public void print() {
         for (String key: Admin.person.get("James").getHashMap().keySet()) {
                 System.out.println(key);
            }

        }
   }
```

Comment: Dont you think it would be better to use getter Methods to access this field as per the programming practices.

Comment: @VivekSingh Encapsulation for static ? Nah. I prefer `Admin.person`